What is the purpose of parentheses around variables being assigned a value?
I'm not sure if this is a Groovy thing or Java thing, I've seen instances of variable assignment such as:
String myVar = ""
...
(myVar) = someMethod(arg1);

do the parenthesis around myVar have any function, or is it just for readability?

If it is for readability purposes then it might be to make it worse readable.

Is that syntax legal in Java?

@aled it is! int x; (x) = 5 + 10; compiles just fine. Along with any number of parentheses, ((((((x)))))) = 5 + 10; compiles as well.

Whether it's legal syntax or not - you'd see it very rarely being used like this in Java. You might see those parentheses around some expressions where they may be meant to increase readability but there are cases where it's actually making things worse.

Gotta agree with those saying it's worse for readability and poor practice.  Please don't.  (Edit: it is definitely not a Java thing, I don't know about Groovy.  I wish they wouldn't.)

@markspace not a groovy thing either...

It appears to be "multiple assignment" construct in Groovy.  Why use it for only one value though, seems confusing.

Yeah, using it like the question is sociopathic

mutliple assignment or array destructuring in JS makes the code worse readable? you so funny!

Groovy
The syntax you have show is a form a destructuring.
1.2.1. Multiple assignment

Groovy supports multiple assignment, i.e. where multiple variables can be assigned at once, e.g.:
def (a, b, c) = [10, 20, 'foo'] 
assert a == 10 && b == 20 && c == 'foo'

You can provide types as part of the declaration if you wish:
def (int i, String j) = [10, 'foo'] 
assert i == 10 && j == 'foo'

As well as used when declaring variables it also applies to existing variables:
def nums = [1, 3, 5] 
def a, b, c 
(a, b, c) = nums 
assert a == 1 && b == 3 && c == 5

The syntax works for arrays as well as lists, as well as methods that return either of these:
def (_, month, year) = "18th June 2009".split() 
assert "In $month of $year" == 'In June of 2009'


It's important to note that destructuring still occurs if you only are assigning one variable within parentheses. It takes the first value from the object being destructured.
def (a) = [2, 4, 5]
assert a == 2

The following will throw an exception because there is nothing to destructure
def (a) = 2

Java
This syntax currently has no meaning, but is legal

It's a "thing" in both a Java and Groovy (as in, it's allowed). Groovy can use that syntax for compound assignment (even though it's only assigning one thing...)
String x, y, z
(x, y, z) = ["1", "2", "3"]

Java doesn't have compound assignment, though. Regardless, the Java Language Specifications 15.26.1 states that you can use any number of pairs of parentheses:

If the left-hand operand expression is a field access expression e.f (§15.11), possibly enclosed in one or more pairs of parentheses, then:

All that matters is that when it's completely evaluated, it's a "field access expression" (or an "an array access expression").


do the parenthesis around myVar have any function

Nope.

or is it just for readability?

I'd argue it hurts readability. Consistency in style matters more, though. Maybe they wanted normal assignments to be consistent between compound assignments?
String a
(a) = "123"

String x, y, z
(x, y, z) = ["1", "2", "3"]


It is not "a thing" in Java ... in the sense that the parentheses have no purpose in Java.  Not from the programming language semantics standpoint, and not from the standpoint of communicating anything meaningful to the reader of the code.  (Hint: there's no such thing as compound assignment in Java. That is a Groovy thing!)

@StephenC I meant it more as being "a thing you can (technically) do", not that its at all useful haha. maybe I didn't word it all to clear.

Yea ... that's not how "its a thing" / "it is not a thing" are typically used: e.g. https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Not%20a%20thing, https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-it-s-not-a-thing.  The bottom line is that no sane Java programmer would recommend writing (a) = b; (in Java).
